# react More Collapse and Expand

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

At first, I want to make only 5 data.text values ​​visible and all data.text to be exposed when the More button is clicked.
Then I want to  only 5 data.text visible when the close button is pressed.

However, in the code I wrote, at first, five are visible, but when the More button is clicked, it doesn't work properly.

How do I modify the code to make it work?

```
   const [visible, setVisible] = useState(5)
   const [expanded, setexpanded ] = useState(false);

      const showMore = () => {
        visible === 5 ? (
            setVisible({ visible: ProductDetail.allergies.length, expanded: true })
         
        ) : (
            setVisible({ visible: 5, expanded: false })
        )
    }

  return (
     
     <ul>
         {ProductDetail && ProductDetail.allergies?.length ? 
                            ProductDetail.allergies.slice(0, 
                           visibleBlogs).map(All => (
                            <li key={All.id}>
                             .....
                             </li>
    </ul>

                    <button type="button" onClick={showMore}>
                        {expanded ? (
                            <span>close</span>
                        ) : (
                            <span>more</span>
                        )}  
                    </button>
                    

                    
)
```

Comment: "data.text seems to disappear completely", where you show data.text? please add more code.

Comment: @AmilaSenadheera 
"Disappears" -> "It doesn't work properly" has been fixed.

Comment: Your `setVisibile` is wrong. You need to set those 2 state separately. `setVisible(5)` or `setVisible(ProductDetail.allergies.length)` and `setExpanded(true)` or `setExpanded(false)`

Comment: @BernhardJosephus   The action works fine, but every time I click I get an error.
`TypeError: setVisible(...) is not a function`

Comment: visible === 5 ? (
I am getting an error in my code here.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite get it. You said the action works fine but you got an error every time you click it, so it doesn't work, no?

Comment: @BernhardJosephus 
The action is good.
But after clicking the button and it works, an error occurs.

Comment: @BernhardJosephus 
`visible === 5 ? (
` The syntax here throws the error `TypeError: setVisible(...) is not a function`.

Comment: @BernhardJosephus  I have entered the code in more detail. This is a method of outputting as slice.

Comment: Can you try first my previous suggestion? I have no idea anymore haha